# flex 4.5.1 color picker

Tags: apache-flex, sdk

So I have a flex app that is using flex 4.5.1 sdk and has a the classic terribly ugly colorpicker.  I've had other flexapps done with other sdks and been able to easily change the swatch colors in the colorpicker.

Is there an easy way to do this with the 4.5.1 sdk as I don't want to upgrade the whole app just to get the colorpicker to look better.

Thanks in advance for your time.

LP

Answer (score 0):

There is only one [Flex ColorPicker](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/ColorPicker.html).  It was introduced in Flex 3.  You should be able to style it using the same method you used in previous (or future) SDKs